# Where can I configure iwconfig wlan0 power on/off?

Tags: wireless, 15.04, power-management, interface

I've noticed that my wlan0 interface has power management on even when I am plugged in. I can turn it off with `sudo iwconfig wlan0 power off`, but it turns on again at reboot or when I unplug my laptop.

How can I get power management to only come on when unplugged and turn off when I'm plugged in?

Using Ubuntu 15.04 with KDE (Kubuntu).

Comment: Try upgrading to 15.10, 15.04 is EoL

Comment: 15.10 fixed the issue. How do I handle this question then? Do I answer it myself, delete it, ask you to answer it, or something else? @praseodym

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading from Kubuntu 15.04 to Kubuntu 15.10 completely fixed the problem.

Also, in Kubuntu 16.04, there is a config file: `/etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/default-wifi-powersave-on.conf`

Changing the `wifi.powersave` from 3 to 2 disables wifi powersaving by default.

Answer (score 0):

Is it a USB-dongle? If yes, this may help:

```
echo 'KERNEL=="wlan*", ACTION=="add", RUN+="/sbin/iwconfig wlan0 power off"' | sudo tee /etc/udev/rules.d/10-wlan-stick.rules
```

Alternatively, there is a script:

```
wget http://media.cdn.ubuntu-de.org/forum/attachments/38/32/4675487-power_d_skripte.tar.gz
sudo tar xvf 4675487-power_d_skripte.tar.gz -C /etc/pm/power.d
```

From here:
https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/sendeleistung-der-wlan-antenne-einstellbar/#post-4675487

Comment: It is integrated wifi with an on/ off switch that I use frequently. The first command looks good but does not account for battery vs. ac status. The script you linked to did not seem to work (and FYI there I found an almost identical script in /usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless).  Any other ideas?

Comment: This udev rule doesn't seem to be limited to USB wireless adapters.